# HTML based Email do not show in Hotmail & Gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email, hotmail

I have a simple Email whose body is in HTML.

This is the simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      .ticket_holder {
      width:800px;
      height:480px;
      background-image:url(http://www.domain.com/img/sorteos/billete_sorteo_24-07-2015.jpg);
      float:left;
      margin:10px auto;
      position:relative;
      }
      .ticket_number {
      width:277px;
      height:60px;
      text-align:center;
      position:absolute;
      top:290px;
      left:450px;
      font-size:42px;
      color:#11AA00;
      font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;
      font-weight:bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ticket_holder">
      <div class="ticket_number">0236</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I will show the content of the Email gotten from a Gmail account. I think there must be an issue related to header but have no idea what should it is.

```
Delivered-To: fran@gmail.com
Received: by 10.37.71.193 with SMTP id u184csp169517yba;
        Fri, 10 Jul 2015 12:10:37 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.129.105.213 with SMTP id e204mr24861296ywc.97.1436555437024;
        Fri, 10 Jul 2015 12:10:37 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com (mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com. [198.2.136.7])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k7si6464663ykd.6.2015.07.10.12.10.36
        for <apalabrados.co@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 10 Jul 2015 12:10:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.136.7 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.2.136.7;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.136.7 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mandrillapp.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com;
 h=From:Sender:Subject:Reply-To:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=contacto@mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com;
 bh=QTHxKn1Liqi9ZJNIUiIqQFl0DNg=;
 b=Wep3W+aIvU17Xwa1SNM0he9Bf403lXYidvKGtwiZpb9QrccWY0DBqImsEqnEGNBKMdSpTd/MdyYW
   k2bgPf/yqHdwNXPDsqS3naEEs/gJC7dfIU+2zvGKp2fpGKsKyzhHkWITEMKV5DoMs3WPNKEPxopx
   l7GY4JpTaaSm7f+4B3M=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com;
 b=JIWGJJlHUZt5grcY4at3yqUabbvCI/KrS/VNplK+n+Ty9cDuCQQEANkExNamBojv+SMXsL8URPnl
   igpbzKkhUk1WEvjufNYp6pZxAPkjHljuLpA+XdnYlgjCzvWJ4gI1QRuq3v5OeXxP6fcebsMSJrhn
   rKWFKYfrMCpZx8v4NXk=;
Received: from pmta04.mandrill.prod.atl01.rsglab.com (127.0.0.1) by mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com id hk0cao1sb1ko for <apalabrados.co@gmail.com>; Fri, 10 Jul 2015 19:09:11 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com>)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mandrillapp.com; 
 i=@mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1436555350; h=From : 
 Sender : Subject : Reply-To : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : 
 Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : 
 List-Unsubscribe; bh=N1DazcpdS55HBslvogsYDTv2iLdRO0rnUDZkh9PCbtQ=; 
 b=OjcMKaAC4K4s1I3fpjFwqMGbYcayh7661XLVARyfmap3g1zZMW/+FWtGU2rzKrIF7wNbtC
 +4E06pOycBBa7Q/D6BGk8CtLQLtWBe260o9X7d4gvBAl70/t0zyqbkucPx82AKzXe956cwsB
 wiBB9xxxmgQdq/LJsmax3b1/+ZRWk=
From: "Contacto impresoras3d.com" <contacto@impresoras3d.com>
Sender: "Contacto impresoras3d.com" <contacto@mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Combinaci=C3=B3n=20Sorteo=2024/07/2015?=
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30672132.55a01856.v1-94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from [188.165.162.97] by mandrillapp.com id 94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda; Fri, 10 Jul 2015 19:09:10 +0000
Reply-To: <contacto@impresoras3d.com>
To: <apalabrados.co@gmail.com>
X-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com
X-Report-Abuse: You can also report abuse here: http://mandrillapp.com/contact/abuse?id=30672132.94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda
X-Mandrill-User: md_30672132
Message-Id: <30672132.20150710190910.55a01856de9973.48448148@mail136-7.atl41.mandrillapp.com>
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 19:09:10 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_av-M8imh9jmVCY5HVEL4ea0TA"

--_av-M8imh9jmVCY5HVEL4ea0TA
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

         0236
--_av-M8imh9jmVCY5HVEL4ea0TA
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset="utf-8">
                                <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                        <style>
                        .ticket_holder {
                                width:800px;
                                height:480px;
                                background-image:url(http://www.impresoras3d.com/img/sorteos/billete_sorteo_24-07-2015.jpg);
                                float:left;
                                margin:10px auto;
                                position:relative;
                        }
                        .ticket_number {
                                width:277px;
                                height:60px;
                                text-align:center;
                                position:absolute;
                                top:290px;
                                left:450px;
                                font-size:42px;
                                color:#11AA00;
                                font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;
                                font-weight:bold;
                        }
                        </style>
                        </head>

                        <body>
                                <div class="ticket_holder">
                                        <div class="ticket_number">0236</div>
                                </div>
                        <img src="http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=30672132&id=94c0ce7842b842caaa20ee481b5d5bda" height="1" width="1"></body>
                        </html>
--_av-M8imh9jmVCY5HVEL4ea0TA--
```

Comment: You shouldn't include external stylesheets in an email and you shouldn't use css style blocks.

Comment: CSS style blocks can be used and should be used for email clients that support it.  Also, CSS should be inlined as well for those email clients that don't support the style block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail strips the head tag and many email clients give limited support on styling of div tags. Your best bet is to convert the div to tables and inline the styles. See [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for CSS compatability and [here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) for an inliner.